# can't invoke static methods in Matlab 7.1.0.246(R14)

Tags: matlab, static-methods

This is a simple .m file. Saved to "temp.m".

In Matlab 7.12.0 (R2011a), I can just call temp.t0() or temp.t1(), it will print the expected results. But in Matlab 7.1.0.246(R14). It shows this error:

> > temp.t0() ??? The function, script, or class temp cannot be indexed using {} or . indexing.

Is it because Matlab version is low, and it doesn't support to invoke static methods?

Below is the source code of temp.m

```
classdef temp
    methods (Static)
        function [] = t0()
            fprintf('function t0\n');
        end
        function [] = t1()
            fprintf('function t1\n');
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

MCOS, the `classdef` syntax for object oriented programming was [not introduced until R2008a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/compatibility-with-previous-versions-.html) (MATLAB 7.6) so MATLAB 7.1 *certainly* doesn't support what you are trying to do, hence the error.

The older release that you have does support [`@classname` folders](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html) for class definitions; however, there is no support for static methods until the introduction of MCOS classes in R2008a.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!